# Number appending other number instead of adding - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying the slice a digit and add it in a `style.backgroundPosition` function but it's always returning 2040 instead of 20 + 20 = 40. This is just an example the actual number to add is dynamically added depending on the `pageYOffset`.

JS:

```
let bg = document.querySelector('body .section_1')

let bgPos = window.getComputedStyle(bg).getPropertyValue('background-position'); // returns '20% 0' (without quotes)
let bgPosNum = bgPos.slice(0, 2)
let bgPosArr = bgPosNum.toString()

document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {                
  let x = window.pageYOffset
  bg.style.backgroundPosition  = '' + (bgPosNum + x/6) + '% 0';            
})
```

Comment: You need to coerce your string `bgPosNum` to number

Comment: a few things wrong, do `bgPos.split('%')[0]` else `100%` will be `10`, then cast your values to numbers before concatenating.  `(Number(bgPosNum) + x/6) + '% 0';`

Comment: @CodeManiac Thank you so much. I thought the browser is returning it as a number instead of string.

Comment: **bgPosNum** is definitely a string in your example code here. If you aren't sure use **typeof(bgPosNum)** in your code.

Comment: Much thanks everyone. The problem is fixed.

Comment: @EssXTee great tip, thanks. It will come in handy. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who replied, I fixed it with Code Maniac's code:

```
let bg = document.querySelector('body .section_1')

let bgPos = window.getComputedStyle(bg).getPropertyValue('background-position');
let bgPosNum = bgPos.slice(0, 2)
let bgPosStr = parseInt(bgPosNum)

document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {                
  let x = window.pageYOffset
  bg.style.backgroundPosition  = '' + (bgPosNum + x/6) + '% 0';            
})
```